# What is complete purpose of a Frame ContentControl in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.forms

I'm quite new to UWP development and even less experienced with Xamarin Forms. I came across a pretty hard to debug situation, which made me think 'What does a Frame really handle under the covers other than only supporting navigation'

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame) the Frame class has this purpose:

> Displays `Page` instances, supports navigation to new pages, and maintains a navigation history to support forward and backward navigation.

In literally all examples I find, the default template in VS for a blank UWP app and the template for Xamarin Forms app I see this code:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        rootFrame = new Frame();
        // some code removed for brevity...

        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }

    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
    }

    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

And this seems fair, because an app will almost certainly need to navigate between multiple pages.

However, when one would use a MVVM framework, e.g. Caliburn Micro, navigation will be handled by this framework and the use of a `Frame` seems useless.

So in my App I chose to remove the template code and put a normal `Page` as rootelement. And this works as expected, it will just show this view.

But when I combined this with Xamarin Forms, together with a [`CommandBar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar) in which I placed a default ['AppBarButton'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton) without an icon set, the app throwed an exception.

When I changed the root element again with a `Frame` the exception went away. Placing a valid Icon in the `AppBarButton` did also made the exception to go away with a normal `Page` as rootelement.

So must the rootelement of the visual tree be a `Frame` in order to let everything work correctly, because apparently a `Frame` has influence on the correct functioning of an `AppBarButton`?

**Edit:**

I'm not really interested in solving the exception. But if it helps explaining what a `Frame` does under the covers, I created a repo [here](https://github.com/TheBigRic/UWP-Xamarin-test)

**Edit 2:**
Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see any stacktrace nor callstack and the description is not much of a help!
[image: Capture]

Comment: In UWP native, this should be valid. You don't have to use a `Frame` if you don't want to. In fact, I never really liked it and rarely use it. I am not sure how X.F does it though.

Comment: When an application throws an exception, it helps to know the exact type, message, inner exceptions, and callstack.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not interested in solving the exceptions, the question is 'What other purposes does a `Frame` have'.
Apart from that, the exception is a `DirectoryNotFoundException` without stacktrace, inner exceptions or clear message. The message is E_UNKNOWN_ERROR

Comment: You surely have a callstack available. Besides, knowing the exceptions may be of help to understand, what purposes the `Frame` class has. That is, if you do not wish to investigate the interfaces it implements, or the anatomy of a UWP application.

Comment: @IInspectable See my edit

Comment: I suppose to get a full callstack you need native debugging enabled, and the debugger set up to break, when a *"Win32 exception"* is thrown. Although I don't know much about using UWP with C#.